# How to execute the BluetoothGatt read and write requests one by one like Queue in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working in BLE android project.After the successful connection status.I can able to discover the gatt services. But the problem is when doing the write/read request simultaneously. The first request is executed successfully and able to get the response in callback method also. Other requests are ignored by OS.Is there any way to execute one by one like Queue.Kindly suggest best way to implement it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Execute one request first, then execute the 2nd request inside the 1st request's reponse callback.

Comment: This is true, but very sad if you want to do more than a couple things in sequence...

Do you know of a good Java/Android way of avoiding "callback hell"? Some sort of queue of Runnables, that gets stepped by the callbacks?

Comment: In BLE you really need to read the callback's result parameter, otherwise you risk of sending, say, 100 queued commands for nothing, in case they start failing at the very first. This standard aims at execution efficiency, not at programmer's avoiding lots of coding.